# Electron JS, start application with Express backend and with separate html front

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, electron

I have an application which has separate ExpressJS backend and separate HTML front.

My ExpressJS backend is located in `root/scripts/server.js`

My HTML front is located in `root/index.html`. This front uses javascript logic, which was generated from `webpack` and it works correctly.

In order to make this project work I first launch my ExpressJS backend with this command:

```
babel-node ./scripts/server.js --presets es2015,stage-0
```

Then I open my `index.html` and everything works fine.

Now I want to pack both backend and front in one desktop application by using ElectronJS.

My project has `main.js` script which launches electron application in desktop mode. And it is located in `root/main.js`. It has following code:

```
const electron = require('electron')
const app = electron.app
const BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow

const path = require('path')
const url = require('url')

let mainWindow

function createWindow () {
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
      width: 800, 
      height: 600,
      autoHideMenuBar: true,
      useContentSize: true,
      resizable: false
  })

  mainWindow.loadURL(url.format({
    pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'),
    protocol: 'file:',
    slashes: true
  }))

  mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools()

  mainWindow.on('closed', function () {
     mainWindow = null
   })
}

app.on('ready', createWindow)

app.on('window-all-closed', function () {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit()
  }
})

app.on('activate', function () {
   if (mainWindow === null) {
     createWindow()
   }
})
```

This script launches **only my HTML front**. What do I need to add, in order to pack Express backend among with HTML front?

Comment: have a look at this one [electron-express](https://github.com/theallmightyjohnmanning/electron-express) and get inspired from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding something like this to main.js:

```
const server = require('./scripts/server');
```